# Connect a Sony HandyCam to a MacBookPro for streaming

Tags: streaming, mac, hdmi, video-capture

I have a Sony HDR-CX330 HandyCam which does a good job recording low light events for us. Now I would like to stream some of these events live.  The Camera has HDMI out, but I'm not sure how I get this into a MacBookPro.  I think I need some kind of capture device but I'm not sure which one or how to search for it.

What do I need to get live video into the laptop?

Comment: What is you budget?  What kind of quality are you looking for?  What infrastructure do you plan to use for live streaming?  These all matter in determining the best approach.

Comment: Also, which model Macbook?  Old ones only have firewire, some have both firewire and thunderbolt, and newer ones only have thunderbolt.

Comment: 2014 MacBookPro. (http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) I'd like a generic solution for streaming: YouTube Live, Skype, etc.  If I could get it to be delectable as a webcam, that would do for now. We are cost conscious.